# Why is page loading treated as a serverless function on Vercel (NextJs)

Tags: next.js, vercel

**Summary**
I have created, and deployed to Vercel, a NextJS app with a Flask backend (serverless function). Note, I am on the hobby plan, so critically I *have a 10s limit on the duration of my serverless functions*.

On my app results page, I make several calls to my backend, each which I have tailored to be less than 10 seconds in duration. The result of these backend calls would populate a component on my page, so I have wrapped that component in Suspense to display some "Loading..." while the data comes in.

The problem I am running into is that my page is timing out before I can complete my backend calls. In the attached snip of my Vercel logs, you can see that navigating to the /results page is considered a serverless function (yellow highlight), and it is timing out, despite my backend API calls (example: green highlight) taking ~5s. What this looks like on the client is, I successfully navigate to the /results page, the Suspense element is shown, then a "Connection Closed" error is shown.

[image: Screenshot of Vercel Logs]

**Question:** Could someone please clarify why my page is being treated as a serverless function, and if this is normal? Could you also suggest any potential workarounds to achieve my functionality? Note, I am hesitant to incorporate a database for ID'ing of fetch requests, but can do if absolutely necessary.

The repo for my project is available [here](https://github.com/dsantos747/so-you-want-to-fly). The "results" page, and the subcomponent "resultsFetch", are likely most relevant.

**Example**
https://eco-flyer-kb5nr49fy-dsantos747.vercel.app

**Steps to Reproduce**
I have provided a link to my deployment. Clicking the green "test button" will attempt to load the results page, and begin the API calls. Wait approximately 10s to see it fail. Note, if it doesn't work at first, please check a "request" cookie has been created.